# ¿Cual es la propiedad para hacer que a la hora de dirigir un enlace a un #id en mi pagina se tarde mas? o sea, transicion

Tags: html, css

quiero hacer que cuando le den clic a mi enlace, que lleva a una misma parte de mi archivo HTML, tenga una transición un poco mas lento, estuve buscando y leyendo, pero no encontré nada. Gracias

Comment: Eso no se hace con css. Mira las [opciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions/behavior) de `scrollTop`.

Comment: con CSS tienes la propiedad [scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) pero no puedes cambia la velocidad y no tiene soporte para algunos navegadores, IE por ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Como te dicen no sería con CSS, esto podrías hacerlo con JavaScript.

Quiza este código te ayude:

```
// Seleccionas todos los elementos con la clase anchor
const anchors  = document.querySelectorAll('.anchor');

// A cada uno se le añade el evento click
anchors.forEach( (anchor) => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{

        // Evita el comportamiento por defecto
        e.preventDefault();

        // Localiza el elemento al que referencia el ancla
        const elm = document.querySelector(anchor.getAttribute('href'));

        // Hace el scroll
        elm.scrollIntoView({block: "start", behavior: "smooth"});
    });
});
```

solo debes incluir este trozo de codigo JavaScript y poner a cada enlace de ancla que tengas la clase CSS anchor y se desplazará con smooth scroll.